# Fetch does not recognize 102 (or any 1xx) status code

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, http-status-codes

I found that `fetch` API always throw `TypeError`, `ERR_EMPTY_REPONSE` or `NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource` for `102` or any code smaller than `200`, regardless of the body of the response.

This took me tremendous time to figure out. Behavior is consistent amongst Fx, Chrome and Opera. I also confirmed that Postman correctly identifies the `102` response.

I wonder why is this happening? `1xx` code should be fine and it is not up to `fetch` to decide whether it is an error. I can't find any document and can't seem to find anyone who is in the same situation.

Is this by design? Or are there anyway to get around this problem? I need `102`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Fetch spec requires browsers to follow the behavior described in the question. See specifically https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-concept-response-status%E2%91%A0%E2%91%A8:

> Any responses whose status is in the range `100` to `199`, inclusive, and is not `101`, are to be ignored.
>
> > *Note: These kind of responses are eventually followed by a "final" response.*

Answer (score 2):

Just to follow up @sideshowbarker and **for Googlers**:

- `1xx` codes are considered informational and **non-final** (except `101` for WebSocket)
- Basically browsers adhere to this definition and **expects more content to follow `1xx` codes**
- I returned `102` and closed connection as would with other response codes
- Browsers see this as an unexpectedly ended connection and complains
- `1xx` responses should be properly completed with other codes (> 199)

And...

- The errors thrown by browsers are too simple to give insights about what real happens
- Partial response (`1xx` codes and body) is ignored thus not recorded by browsers and will **NOT** show up in the console, further complicates the problem
- Even `999` will work for browsers as these are not ignored like `1xx` codes

So...

- Do not use `1xx` unless you want keep some long running connections or use WebSocket
- When signify "Request received, I'm processing it, come back later", do not use `102 Processing`, but `202 Accepted` for acknowledgement